# Pass environment variable through PM2 to NextJS

Tags: shell, npm, next.js, pm2

I have 2 `package.json` scripts that look like this:

```
"start": "next start -p $PORT",
"pm2_staging": "pm2 restart ecosystem.config.js --env staging",
```

And an `ecosystem.config.js` that looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'test.co.uk',
      script: 'npm',
      args: 'start',
      env_staging: {
        API: 'staging',
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
        PORT: 3001,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

I then run the following:

```
TEST_VAR='test' npm run pm2_staging
```

I would expect the following to happen:

- The PM2 restart command fires
- `ecosystem.config.js` fires the `npm start` command and sets some environment variables
- The app starts and all env vars are available, including `TEST_VAR` (set in the original command)

What actually happens is all the env vars from the ecosystem are correctly set, but TEST_VAR is not available in the app. Why is this and how do I go about setting secret keys from CI tools if I can't do this?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem tonight. After looking every where I found the config needed. The env variable needs to go in your `ecosystem.config.js` like below. In my case I put it at the root of my server

```
  module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'nextjs',
    script: 'yarn',
    args:"start",
    cwd:"/var/www/myapp/",
    instances: 2,
    autorestart: true,
    watch: false,
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'development'
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production',
      API_URL: 'YOUR ENV URL',
      PORT:8000
    }
  }]
};
```

`package.json` like so

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 8000"
  },
...
```

and executed something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/myapp/
git pull && yarn install && yarn build
cd ~/
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production
```

Then the `API_URL` would be available in `const API_URL = process.env.API_URL` in your app.
These urls helped
https://willandskill.se/en/setup-a-next-js-project-with-pm2-nginx-and-yarn-on-ubuntu-18-04/
https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/

Answer (score 1):

Another idea would be passing **all** the `env` parameters of PM2 to the server via the following.

`ecosystem.config.js` being:

```js
module.exports = {
    apps: [{
        name: "my-service-1",
        script: "dist/server.js",
        env_production: process.env, // pass all the env params of the container to node
    }],
};
```

Answer (score 1):

@webface

The environment variables in your example will not be available in Nextjs. To be available to both the client and server, variables must be prefixed with NEXT_PUBLIC (ie. NEXT_PUBLIC_API_VERSION).

These environment variables must be passed into the build process to be available at runtime.